# HTML/DOM for a page with random image which will post properly in facebook and google+

Tags: html, facebook, image, dom, random

I have a website which contains the cute conceit of a random headshot.  Every time you load the page (or click the headshot), it gets replaced with a new headshot.  It works great until I post a link to the website on Facebook.

What happens then is when Facebook scans the page for images, it doesn't find the random image, I assume because it doesn't run the scripts.  I would love for the facebook thumbnail to also have a random image.

Is there any way to solve this without resorting to server side code?

Here's what I do now:

in head-script section

```
var lastTimeout = 0;
var lastHeadNum = 0;

function headURL(headCount)
{
    url = "/public/images/heads/mtoy";
    if( headCount < 10 )
        url += "0";
    url += headCount.toString();
    url += ".gif";
    return url;
}

function headshotImage()
{
    lastHeadNum = Math.floor((Math.random()*87)+1);
    document.write('<img id="headshot" src="' + headURL(lastHeadNum) + '" onclick="next_headshot();" width=150 height=150>\n');
    lastTimeout = setTimeout("next_headshot();", 12000);
}

function next_headshot()
{
    if (lastTimeout != 0)
        clearTimeout(lastTimeout);
    do {
        headNum = Math.floor((Math.random()*87)+1);
    } while (headNum == lastHeadNum);
    lastHeadNum = headNum;
    document.getElementById('headshot').src = headURL(headNum);;
    lastTimeout = setTimeout("next_headshot();", 12000);
}
```

then later in the body-html

```
<div id="contents">
<script type="text/javascript">headshotImage();</script>
<H1 class="contenthead">Table of Contents</H1>
```

in a previous incarnation, the body-html looked like:

```
<div id="contents">
<img id="headshot" src="" onclick="next_headshot();">
<H1 class="contenthead">Table of Contents</H1>
```

and then i had a body.onload handler to call next_headshot the first time, and that had the same problem with Facebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want Facebook to have a *random* image, then I think you need server-side code. But if you're happy with a fixed image, then look into OpenGraph. You should be able to put this in your `<head>` section:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="/public/images/heads/mtoy01.gif"/>
```

Another approach is to put the `<img>` tag right into the HTML (instead of generating it procedurally) and hard-code it to one image. It won't give you the initially-random image, though you could probably swap it out immediately on page load.

Comment: [https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/snippet/] documents google+ snippet construction.  Recently Google+ started failing to use the og:image unless the content properly was a full URL.